# How to turn all NAs between two strings in column with the string before the NAs

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace, na

I'm currently working with FBI crime data that takes all city crime data within each state and provides statistics for it. I am trying to figure out a way to copy each state string (which is only shown once per all cities in a state, at the first line for that state) and extend it to every line before the next state.

I could do this in excel, but it's given the extent of all the files I'm working with, it is far less efficient.

```r
 State  City  Population `Violent crime` `Murder and non… 
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>           
1 ALAB… Abbe…       2955               8                0               
2 NA    Adam…       4771              53                0               
3 NA    Addi…        720               4                0               
4 NA    Alab…      28904              33                1               
5 NA    Alex…      15053             131                2              
6 NA    Alic…       2457               3                0               
7 ARK.. Mel..        382 .             1                2 
8 NA    Broe..       471              53                0               
9 NA    Semf..        72               2                0               
10 NA   Bares…      28904              33                1               
11 NA   Ferat…      1523             31                2              
12 NA   Atews…       1457               4                0
```

I would like to replace those NAs with Alabama since they are all cities in Alabama and all the NAs after Arkansas with Arkansas until the next state and so on and so forth. This list continues through the entire country so it's pretty exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

One option is `fill` which would replace the NA elements with the previous non-NA element as the `.direction` is "down" by default

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    fill(State)
```

If we want to change in both direction or reverse, just change the `.direction`.  It can take values as

```
.direction = c("down", "up", "downup", "updown")
```